# Batch file to append several text documents to one document

Tags: batch-file, syntax

I have created a batch file which should do several things, including appending all text documents of a certain format into one text file provided there are more than one text files of this format in the directory. This section of the code is below:

```
:multiple
SET /a count=0
ECHO.> "%location%\UAV_camera_coords_all.txt"
FOR /r "%location%\Output" %%G in ("UAV_camera_coords_*.txt") do set /a count+=1
IF %count% GTR 1 (
FOR /r "%location%\Output" %%G in ("*.txt") DO (
SET file=%%~G
TYPE "%file%">>"%location%\UAV_camera_coords_all"
)
GOTO :end
```

It seems that the code is crashing upon reaching the if statement even though the count variable is greater than one. None of the code in the if statement is executed and indeed none of the code which should come after the if statement is executed either. Is there any syntax or other error which may be causing this?

Comment: I really see no point at all using two `FOR` commands.  All you should need is the second `FOR` block without the `SET` command.  All you are doing is slowing down execution.

Comment: Another inefficiency is the file output.  If you put output redirection on the outside of the `FOR` block after the closing parentheses, the code would execute much quicker.  That way the output file stays open and the file pointer keeps its position.  In your current code you are opening and closing the output file for every input file you want to append to the output file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides my comment. I assume that you are not really planning on typing the output of `*.txt` but instead only `UAV_camera_coords_*.txt`.. if not, feel free to change it back to `*.txt`

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=1,*" %%i in ('dir /s "%location%\UAV_camera_coords_*.txt" ^| findstr "File(s)"') do set cnt=%%i
if %cnt% gtr 1 (
    for /f %%a in ('dir /b /s "%location%\UAV_camera_coords_*.txt"') do type "%%~a"
)>"%location%\UAV_camera_coords-all.txt"
```

Note, I changed the output filename to be `-all` and not `_all` as that would type the file onto itself if it was to be a `txt` file as well.

**Edit** adding back original answer, before I realised you were recursively searching through directories:

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=1,*" %%i in ('dir "UAV_camera_coords_*.txt" ^| findstr "File(s)"') do if %%i gtr 1 type "UAV_camera_coords_*.txt">>"%location%\UAV_camera_coords_all"
```

Comment: Note that UAV_coords_all and the other text files are in different directories. It seems your original unedited answer works fine.

Comment: The reason I changed it was because I only later realised you were recursing through sub directories.

Answer (score 0):

Just for the purpose of providing an alternative, this one uses [xcopy](/questions/tagged/xcopy) to check the file count, and [copy](/questions/tagged/copy) to merge them.

```batch-file
PushD "%location%\Output" 2>NUL && For /F %%G In ('""%__AppDir__%xcopy.exe" "UAV_camera_coords_*.txt" . /SQL"')Do If %%G Gtr 1 Copy /Y /B "UAV_camera_coords_*.txt" "..\UAV_camera_coords_all.txt">NUL & PopD
```